# Is there any opensource “MSWord doc to PDF” convert library available

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert word(.doc/.docx format) into PDF on android device. Is there an opensource solution where I can use as a java library or something?.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of an end to end conversion project but you could take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to parse/extract information from a MS Word document and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) to create PDF files from a Java program.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. apache POI converts word into html and with iText we can create pdf files but output will be - Not supporting tables css styles, and genrated pdf is not in proper format.. so if some other api is available in java . please reply..thanks

Comment: @user1212 Please share if you found any solution !!